# override default values in application.yml file spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the below configuration file. If you look at the below file, i have 
    prop.responseConfig.default, these values needs to be read for both android and ios 
                    based on device. For ios, we have ios.actionLink.target name is different. so i want to 
                    override that value alone ( means instead of REPLACE-LINK', it should be 'LOST-DEEPLINK') 
                    and rest of the values should be same. similarly, lets say for android if you have 
                    any value which is different from default values, then it should be overridden and rest 
                    should remain same (in this case android.actionSwitch.method). Can some body please provide a solution or sample code for the same?

```
        prop:
          responseConfig:
            default:
              label1: 'label1'
              actionSwitch:
                target: 'some url'
                method: 'PUT'
                errorResponse: 'Its an error message'
              actionLink:
                target: 'REPLACE-LINK'
                data:
                  EXTRA_UUID: '{Id}'
            ios:     
              actionLink:
                target: 'LOST-DEEPLINK'
            android:     
              actionSwitch::
                 method: 'GET'

    private String target;
        private Map<String, String> data;
        private String method;
        private String cin;
        private String errorResponse;
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can solve it by defining config in such way:

```
 prop:
  responseConfig:
    ios: true
    default:
      label1: 'label1'
      actionSwitch:
        target: 'some url'
        method: 'PUT'
        errorResponse: 'Its an error message'
      actionLink:
        target: 'REPLACE-LINK'
        data:
          EXTRA_UUID: '{Id}'
    ios:     
      actionLink:
        target: 'LOST-DEEPLINK'
    android:     
      actionSwitch::
         method: 'GET'
```

Then in your config you can for example rely on those variable:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("prop.responseConfig.default")
public class Config{

@Value("${prop.responseConfig.ios}")
private boolean isIos;

@Value("${ios.actionSwitch.target}")
private String iosActionLinkTarget;

@Value("${android.actionSwitch.method}")
private String androidActionSwitchMethod;

private ActionSwitch actionSwitch;
private ActionLink actionLink;


public ActionLink getActionLink(){
 if(isIos){
   actionLink.setTarget(iosActionLinkTarget);
 }
return this.actionSwitch;
}

public ActionSwitch getActionSwitch(){
 if(!isIos){
   actionSwitch.setMethod(androidActionSwitchMethod);
 }
return this.actionSwitch;
}




@Getter
@Setter
public static ActionSwitch{
  private String target;
  private String method;
  private String errorResponse;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public static ActionLink{
  private String target;
  private Data data; 
}

@Getter
@Setter
public static Data{
 private String EXTRA_UUID;
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am externalizing this yml file using config server and i am using @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prop.responseConfig") to read these properties. In this case how do we implement the above solution? Thanks !

Comment: Just for clarification spring cloud config server ?

Comment: If it’s spring cloud config server you can place property in src/main/resources/application.yml and it will be overrided after you get config from config server

Comment: Yes ! using spring cloud config server, it has been externalized. Its not part of my code base. We dont want this to be part of src/main/resources/ as the value keeps changing and every time  we need to build and deploy.

Comment: Please test and let me know

Comment: @ Mykhailo Moskura we dont want to keep the application.yml file inside the src/main/resources folder. is there any other way to do this?

Comment: If you are using @ConfigurationProperties and storing into the map you can add one more property with boolean value and if it’s true just override target as key in the map

Comment: It’s only one way which I see

Comment: Do you want more details?

Comment: Updated an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184843/discussion-between-mykhailo-moskura-and-user2334926).